# ExtJS 6 how to set Ext,panel.Panel items dynamically

Tags: extjs

I need to update the items on a mounted Panel from the responses on an AJAX request.

I have this panel:

```
Ext.define('myComponents.MyPanelView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    id: 'idMyPanel',
    itemId: 'idMyPanel',
    alias: 'widget.WidgetMyPanel',
    scrollable: true,
    requires: [],
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 4,
        tableAttrs: {
            style: {
                width: '100%',
                padding: '10px'
            }
        },
        tdAttrs: {
            style: {
                'vertical-align': 'top'
            }
        }
    },
    items: [
    ],

    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

and in a controller I have this:

```
Ext.define('myComponents.myController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.MyController',
    requires: [],
    views: ['myComponents.MyPanelView'],
    stores: [],
    models: [],

    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'WidgetMyPanel #deployer': {
                'itemclick': function (treenode, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'myURL',
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers,
                    success: function (response) {

                        const myComponent = Ext.getCmp('idMyPanel');

                        // myComponent.setItems( items from the response )
                        //                ^
                        //                |---- I need something here to update the items

                    },
                    failure: function (response) { console.log('Failure'); }
                });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I tried

```
myComponent.items.items = [ //... items here ]
```

and it shows no error, but does not update the view. Also tried:

```
myComponent.items.items.push( //... items here )
```

again no error but the view remains with no changes.

I need every time the response is successfull the items to be displayed, but I can't figure it out how to do so. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `add()` method from Ext.Panel.
`myComponent.add(item);`

Comment: Thank you. I must say that I needed to add the `removeAll()` method before and the `updateLayout()` method after. You saved my day!